# Android Edittext - Keyboard overlap the edittext when the edittext exceed the max length

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my `Activity`, I have a `EditText` field that will be pushed up by keyboard so user can input like normal. But just when user enter exceed the max length of this `EditText`, the `EditText` field being pulled down and behind the keyboard, so user cannot see the field anymore.

My `xml` layout:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtDescription"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_login_customize"
    android:ems="15"
    android:fontFamily="OpenSans-Light"
    android:hint="@string/td_hint_description"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
    android:maxLength="150"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColorHint="@drawable/hint_text_color"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_13" />
```

And my `Manifest`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.TransferEnterDetailsActivity"
    android:configChanges="locale"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

And I'm in Full Screen theme.

Any suggestion is appriciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" `

Comment: Use  android:singleLine="true" .... It can be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

Add this property in your .xml file,

I was having same problem than i solved as below ,

```
             <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editMsj"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:hint="Enter Message"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textPostalAddress"
                android:minHeight="200dip"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="#80000000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal_size" />
```

in **AndroidManifest**

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it was not work in my case. I suspect it's a android bug with the keyboard, when we exceed the max length of the text box, it lost focus.